# How does Windows Hibernation works

Tags: .net, windows

Out of curiosity, I was looking for an article/documentation on "how windows hibernate option work", i.e. when one selects "Hibernate" option in windows shutdown dialog. The reply I got from some sources was that, its mere serialization of memory and registers.

Pardon me if I am wrong here. If windows could serialize any applications, process or objects regardless of whether its serializable or non-serializable, how come .NET limits serializable objects to those with [Serializable] attribute or ISerializable interface?

Comment: I don't see how serialization in the .NET framework is related to hibernating. The Windows core wasn't written using the .NET framework. Serialization in this case is not the same as serializing objects.

Comment: Something a little more level that not involves .NET at all :)

Comment: AFAIK binary serialization is possible on any .NET object. Unrelated to your question though.

Comment: @jishi - depends what you mean... BinaryFormatter insists on either `[Serializable]` or `ISerializable`; other binary serializers have different requirements. But in many cases (a file handle, for example), it makes no sense to serialize it. It has no way of recreating a file handle (by itself).

Comment: What made me to ask this was, though .NET is said to be managed it still had to rely upon umanaged APIs to execute tasks like System. Diagnostics.process.Start(), so if thats the case, could the serialization functionality too be shared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside a process address-space, everything is just bytes; some stack, some managed heap, etc. Bytes are *inherently* serializable - they are just bytes. All hibernate has to do is suspend the threads and write the entire address space to disk.

With *objects*, you want to save them to some out-of-memory structure. Unfortunately, it makes **no sense** to store addresses etc, as it is *exceptionally* unlikely to rehydrate into exactly the same point in memory. Additionally, many things like unmanaged object handles **will make no sense** when rehydrated. It is also extremely likely that you want to save just a *small* block of objects, not an entire process space. And even in a small graph, those objects could be scattered **all over** the place - so you can't just copy out a few pages of memory.

Also keep in mind that a common use of serialization is to deep-clone objects; if you relied on the in-memory representation of objects, you would have to deserialize to exactly the same place in memory - so you can't have cloned *anything*. And that is **before* you touch on concepts such as compacting garbage collectors, which move objects around in memory while you aren't looking.

Also consider that you might be loading the data into a different platform / architecture, or want to write a specific format (xml, json, etc).

So instead of just copying raw memory, serialization code must look at individual objects, traversing references and writing an object graph in a way that allows rehydration from a source that has **nothing at all** to do with raw memory. Much harder.

Comment: @Marc, What do you mean by (re)Hydrate?

Comment: So Serialization is more complex than the hibernation stuff. The platform\architecture agnostic point which you had mentioned is a valid point.

Comment: @Sanjeevakumar in this context, synonymous with "deserialize" or "materialize"; get an object graph back from the persisted stream

Comment: @AbrahamJP - but just loading that data into a different process on the same machine, or back into the *same* process space at a later point in time - all of these things would die horribly if it relied on just raw memory.

Comment: @Marc Thanks. I was trying to read between the lines because of this word.

Comment: @Marc: You are right, if going for platform agnostic serializtion. what if its in the same machine. At times while developing windows application I felt like having a feature to serialize the entire application to disk instead of asking a couple of prompts to save all those left opened\unsaved. The same app cane be opened back on the same machine at a later time in the same state as it was.

Comment: @AbrahamJP even then, serializing the *object model* might make sense - but serializing an *application*? less so. You also have unmanaged handles to consider - you cannot serialize/deserialize them unless the entire windows system is being serialized.

Comment: @Marc: Thanks for your reply. If you have any link to windows hibernation internals, could you please share it. So what I learnt from here is that serialization is particularly applicable to objects alone while windows hibernation is for an entire system memory space.

Comment: @AbrahamJP - I've never looked much at that; I worry mainly about object models etc ;p

Answer (score 2):

These are two very different things. Windows has control of what is in memory at any given time, and has direct access to the hardware. "Serialization" is one word to describe what it does to support hibernation I suppose, but it's not the same concept as in the CLR.

In .NET serialization is an explicit operation generally initiated by the developer; the attribute tells the framework that your type marked with it can be streamed out and back in without worrying about state or variance in behavior.

Technically the CLR can serialize anything I suppose, after all it has access to the underlying representation of each type, and keeps track of each object instance. So I guess you could "hibernate" an entire app domain at any given point; that would be closer to what Windows does.

Comment: Strictly speaking, windows *doesn't* have direct access to the hardware; it runs inside a hardware-abstraction-layer, and even that could be inside a virtual-machine, which could be either a hypervisor or supervisor mode. Lots of layers between the OS and the hardware.

Comment: Yes as you said, if an application is entirely depending on .NET classes and opting for binary serialization, then I believe there could be something API or functionality that could be shared between windows and .NET (only on windows platforms) for serializing the objects  without the address space information.

Comment: @Marc - ultimately though, the kernel has all the access it needs or wants.